# Merge two php arrays (or more) to one table

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have 2 arrays:

array 1 contains 2 products.

```
[records] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [productID] => 3347
                    [amountInStock] => 2.000000
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [productID] => 6798
                    [amountInStock] => 1.000000
                )
    )
```

array 2 contains 3 products. one product is in array one also

```
[records] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [productID] => 3347
                    [amountInStock] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [productID] => 6332
                    [amountInStock] => 1.000000
                )
        [2] => Array
                (
                    [productID] => 6922
                    [amountInStock] => 3.000000
                )
    )
```

now i need to merge 2 arrays to table like this

```
product | array 1   |  array 2

3347      2            0
6798      1            0
6332      0            0
6922      0            2
```

What should i do

Comment: It seems simple enough - but there are about a million ways to do it. Have you tried anything so far - or are you completely stumped?

Answer (score 1):

Use `foreach` and add elements to new array.

```
$new = [];

foreach ($array1 as $element) {
   if (isset($new[$element['productID']])) {
       $new[$element['productID']]['array 1'] = $element['ammountInStock'];
   } else {
       $new[$element['productID']]['array 1'] = $element['ammountInStock'];
       $new[$element['productID']]['array 2'] = 0;
   }
}

foreach ($array1 as $element) {
   if (isset($new[$element['productID']])) {
       $new[$element['productID']]['array 2'] = $element['ammountInStock'];
   } else {
       $new[$element['productID']]['array 2'] = $element['ammountInStock'];
       $new[$element['productID']]['array 1'] = 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to accomplish what you are looking for is using [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

```
<?php
$arr1 = array(
          array('productID' => 3347,
                'amountInStock' => 2.000000
                ),
          array('productID' => 6798,
                'amountInStock' => 1.000000
                )
        );

$arr2 = array(
          array('productID' => 6332,
                'amountInStock' => 3.000000
                ),
          array('productID' => 6330,
                'amountInStock' => 4.000000
                )
        );

$arr = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);

var_dump($arr);
?>
```

Demo: https://eval.in/205237

EDIT:
If you want to prevent duplicate entries, try using [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) as well.

Demo: https://eval.in/205238